# Get total no of column without select column value in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table that look like this.

```
id | FirstName | lastName | age 
--------------------------------
01 | Ayodya    | madusanka| 22
02 | praneeth  | praneeth | 23
03 | madusanka | praneeth | 25
04 | praneeth  | madusanka| 33
05 | damith    | asanka   | 43
06 | damith    | danushka | 22
07 | damith    | chanaka  | 33
08 |asanka     | damith   | 44
```

But I want to calculate totla no of count in `FirstName` column without `praneeth` data count should not include in above total no fo count.
Answer is total count = 6 , because two `praneeth` values include table no.
How I create sql query for get above count.
I cannot used (TotalCount - TotalNoFoCount in `praneeth1)

Comment: You want to exclude rows `WHERE FirstName = 'praneeth'`?

Answer (score 0):

What i assume from your question it should like this

```
select count(DISTINCT FirstName) From your_table;
```